# how do you add multiple variables that represent a percentage of a total

Tags: percentages

I believe the answer is fairly straightforward but fear it can not be that simple.

The problem i want to solve involves multiple variables, lets call them A,B,X,Y. Each of these variables represents a value between 1 and 100. They each have a percentage influence on a total, T, that is also a value between 1 and 100. T is unknown, and A,B,X,Y are known. the specific values arent important. Am i correct to assume that the equation is as simple as multiplying each variable by its percentage of influence then adding these together?

So for example
10%(A) + 25%(B) + 35%(X) + 30%(Y) = T

Answer (score 1):

You have reinvented the idea of a *weighted average*. It's probably the right solution to your problem. I can't be sure without knowing something about the meanings of the variables.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean